# Is there a way to know, if input value was changed by webpage or user?

Tags: javascript

So, is there a way to know, if input value was changed by webpage or user? For example, a input, I change its value with script help (GreaseMonkey), and I need to know if the value is changed/cleared by webpage or the user. This is what I have so far, will reset value, if there was any changes made.

```
if (firstInput.value != email) {
    firstInput.focus();
    firstInput.value = email;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an event listener to the "change" event? Basically when something modifies the value, it should trigger a "change" event. At least, user interactions.

Comment: @Cronco: User interactions *will* trigger this, that's for sure; however, will programmatic changes also trigger?

Comment: @Piskvor, @Cronco: No, they will not. `change` is checked and invoked when the `blur` event of the input occurs.

Comment: Yes, this kinda won't work, tried changing input value from webpage, event didn't trigger.

Comment: @nuclear: Do you want to know when the user/page is *done* changing the field, or as it's being changed?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler: being changed. but the first option could work too.. the page i am working on is http://freecandy.ax.lt/index.php and the problem is, inputs changes onFocus. >_< I do not wan't to make any changes to DOM, only input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no. If you're in control of the page, you could make every change to the form fields through a wrapper function - and then check if the value is the same; if not, the user made a change.

Alternately, you could register for keystroke events, but this will not capture e.g. copying and pasting.

Comment: good idea, but isn't it possible to set onkeypress on input, without setting attribute (modifying DOM)? My example doesn't work sadly. `document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener("onKeypress", function() { alert("te") }, true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript event handler onKeyUp [jQuery: keyup()] to determine if the user pressed any keys. This should help to distinguish between automated and manual changes.

Reference:
http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/evhan_onkeyup.html
http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: *[right click][Paste]* - no keypresses at all, yet the user has changed the element's content.